# Group by Year and Month Panda Pivot Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data like this

```
    Date    LoanOfficer     User_Name       Loan_Number
0   2017-11-30 00:00:00 Mark Evans      underwriterx    1100000293
1   2017-11-30 00:00:00 Kimberly White  underwritery    1100004947
2   2017-11-30 00:00:00 DClair Phillips underwriterz    1100007224
```

I've created df pivot table like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=["User_Name","LoanOfficer"],
               values=["Loan_Number"],
               aggfunc='count',fill_value=0,
               columns=["Date"]
                      )
```

However I need the Date column to be grouped by Year and Month. I was looking at other solutions of resampling the dataframe and then applying the pivot but it only does it for Month and Days. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert you Date column to %Y-%m , then do the `pivot_table`

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.Date=df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df
Out[143]: 
      Date      LoanOfficer     User_Name  Loan_Number
0  2017-11       Mark Evans  underwriterx   1100000293
1  2017-11   Kimberly White  underwritery   1100004947
2  2017-11  DClair Phillips  underwriterz   1100007224

pd.pivot_table(df,index=["User_Name","LoanOfficer"],
               values=["Loan_Number"],
               aggfunc='count',fill_value=0,
               columns=["Date"]
                      )
Out[144]: 
                             Loan_Number
Date                             2017-11
User_Name    LoanOfficer                
underwriterx Mark Evans                1
underwritery Kimberly White            1
underwriterz DClair Phillips           1
```